# How can i add a child to a list of data on firebase that has a unique name?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase database:

[image]

All I am trying to do is add data to this child(-M0h3ipBGdzHBuH129WT) without overwriting anything. Is there a way to do so? 
Currently the code below creates a todolist,

```
const task = document.getElementById('task');
const userId = document.getElementById('userId');
const childreference = document.getElementById('childreference').value
const addtodolistcontent = document.getElementById('addtodolistcontent')
const database = firebase.database();
const usersRef = database.ref('todolist_users');

createtodolist.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const usersRef = database.ref('todolist_users');
    e.preventDefault();
    const autoId = usersRef.push().key
    usersRef.child(autoId).set({
        userId: userId.value,
        task: task.value
    })
});
```

And the second code snippet, I am trying to reference that unique ID and add to it.

```
addtodolistbtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
e.preventDefault();
firebase.database().ref('todolist_users/' + childreference).push({
    task2: addtodolistcontent.value
}) });
```

Another problem i have just thought is that if i can get this to work, i need another way of making a task 3,4,5 and so on.

Is this a complicated way of making a simple todo list where you can add and delete as you please? If so how else can i make it?

Comment: I've made the image visible. But for future questions please post the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

`push()` method will create a new child everytime you add, if you want to add it under the unique `userId`, then you need to use the following:

```
firebase.database().ref('todolist_users/' + childreference).child(userId).push({
    task2: addtodolistcontent.value
})
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set

Comment: I think OP may want to use `push()` instead of `set()` under the `child(userId)`, so that each user can have multiple tasks.

Comment: Yes you're right  updated the answer to use `push()` under userId

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working for me, im not sure if ive made it clear what I want. All i need is to add a child to the list of data with the unique id (-M0h3ipBGdzHBuH129WT as shown in the picture). I want it so the way to select it is but typing in that long unique number, and then adding the child. Is it possible?